# Execute a method right after tableview delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wanted to highlight a particular row in a tableview(even after refreshing the values in it). But each time when I refresh the table using

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

the highlighted selection is gone.

```
-(void) loadValues {

[tableView reloadData];

[self displaySelection];

}
```

When I checked the flow of execution, I found out that only after the displaySelection method, the tableView's delegate methods are executed.

I've used a variable as a flag to check for the last row in the 'cellForRow' method to solve my problem. But I really wanted to know is there any other way to check that the tableView's delegate methods are executed completely so that 'displaySelection' will be executed only after it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like:

```
[tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This should actually block your thread until the tableview gets reloaded.